# how to bind to the results of a query in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a query that hits a service and returns the results back to me as an indexed collection

```
static void QueryActivities()
{
    QueryClient qc = new QueryClient("BasicHttpBinding_IQuery");
    QueryFilter filter = new QueryFilter();
    filter.CallForService = false;
    var result = qc.GetFilteredActivityIndex(filter);
    result.Clone(); //inserted this just to test return in debug mode
}
```

WHen this is executed I get a return of 5 records ( actually five rows of data with multiple values per each row. id, type, date, address etc).

I would like to bind this return to a gridview within a WPF application. Is there a way to refernce and bind to result variable or do I need to create a new collection and then add the return of result to the new collection?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way with WPF Toolkit's DataGrid. However, I would create a custom object and make an `ObservableCollection` of that object and bind to it. The [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) is a collection meant for this type of use and you can bind the elements inside your custom object to the different elements in your gridview.

**Update:**

Based on your comment it feels as if you need a good tutorial for binding with MVVM. The best tutorial I have seen on this is [Jason Dolinger's](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650) tutorial. It helps you bind associated properties from a collection of a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

A new class(ViewModel) level Collection with its associated property would be better.

Comment: could you provide a snippet of sample code for this? When you state associated properties are you referring to setting up a dependency property on the view? I'm good with the binding part (control to collection) but not the part on binding the return to a new collection.  This is somehting I thinkk would really be useful to learn. In the above snippet I haven't been able to pass the result to new collection.
Thank you!

Comment: @randyc: What's the type of `result`?

Comment: @randyc: In case you're still struggling... `result = new ObservableCollection(qc.GetFilteredActivityIndex(filter));` where result is a property of type `ObservableCollection`. you can now bind this result to your control. We use ObservableCollection to notify changes when property or collection itself is changed.

Comment: Got it working but thanks on the tip for creating the Collection

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I found that I could bind directly to the query. The variabl;e results acts as it's own List Collection. That being said I have been able to display the data using:

```
    private void QueryActivities()
    {
        QueryClient qc = new QueryClient("BasicHttpBinding_IQuery");
        QueryFilter filter = new QueryFilter();
        filter.CallForService = false;
        var result = qc.GetFilteredActivityIndex(filter);

        this.actGridView.ItemsSource = result; //binds to the gridview
    }
```

Thanks for all the comments on using collections.